# The Alias directive will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias

Tags: httpd, apache-2.4, centos7, mod-alias

Ok, not sure why this is occuring.

So, I get the message

```
The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
```

and

```
The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf at line 18 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
```

but here are the first 15 lines of my `/httpd/httpd.conf` file

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen *:80
Listen *:443

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin hostmaster@localhost
ServerName 192.168.1.200:80

Include conf.d/*.conf  <- THIS IS WHERE INCLUDES BEGIN
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
```

There are absolutely no `Alias or ScriptAlias` entries before line 14, which is the `Include conf.d/*.conf`.

So, in reality, the first time an `Alias` entry is encountered, is in fact in the `awstats.conf` file under `/conf.d/*.conf`.

Why is it that I am getting this error then?

The server runs, it's just an annoyance.

**EDIT: did grep Alias on `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf` and here are the results ->**

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf:Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/classes/"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf:Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/css/"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf:Alias /awstatsicons "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/icon/"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf:ScriptAlias /awstats/ "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:Alias /noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:Alias /noindex/css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
```

Comment: Thanks but I just updated the debug command: `grep -E "Alias|Redirect" conf.d/*.conf`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest to understand is that Apache generates a single configuration file internally, by parsing the main httpd.conf line by line and includes the external sections at the locations where the [**`Include`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) or the [**`IncludeOptional`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#includeoptional) directive is used, before continuing with the next line.

When wildcards are used in `Include` file-system paths the includes are parsed in lexicographical (dictionary) order, `conf.d/alice.conf`  will come before `conf.d/bob.conf`.

With many directives order matters, with some the last occurrence is used, with others a greater scope before a smaller scope will win etc.

The rules for the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive are:

> Aliases and Redirects occurring in different contexts are processed
>   like other directives according to [standard merging rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging). But when
>   multiple Aliases or Redirects occur in the same context (for example,
>   in the same  section) they are processed in a particular
>   order.
>
> First, *all Redirects are processed before Aliases* are processed, and
>   therefore a request that matches a `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` will
>   never have Aliases applied. Second, the Aliases and Redirects are
>   processed in the order they appear in the configuration files, with
>   **the first match taking precedence**.
>
> For this reason, when two or more of these directives apply to the
>   same sub-path, you must list the most specific path first in order for
>   all the directives to have an effect. For example, the following
>   configuration will work as expected:
>
> ```
> Alias /foo/bar /baz 
> Alias /foo /gaq
> ```
>
> But if the above two directives
>   were reversed in order, the `/foo` Alias would always match before the
>   `/foo/bar` Alias, so the latter directive would be ignored.

For troubleshooting a good first start in your case is a simple `grep -E "Alias|Redirect" conf.d/*.conf`

Comment: Added the output of grep Alias to my Post.

Comment: same output. not sure what that means

Comment: Then I'm a bit lost too!

Comment: OK, so I'm not the only one :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error resulting from incorrect Host Configuration.
To resolv it simply add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Here Host Configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

Check configure vhost.
In my case the error caused the wrong configuration of the virtual host.
It looked like this:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/hitman.conf

```
ServerAdmin marek@localhost
ServerName hitman
DocumentRoot /home/marek/public_html/hitman
```

correct configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin marek@localhost
ServerName hitman
DocumentRoot /home/marek/public_html/hitman
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I find it very unclear what your proposed solution is.

Comment: A more detailed description of the problem solution.
I hope that helps.